# LogManager.GetLogger in Powershell Module returns multiple objects

Tags: powershell, module, nlog

I am trying to wrap the nlog.dll in a module so i can reuse that mechanism for multiple scripts.

In the module I do this:

```
Set-StrictMode -Version Latest

function Get-NewLoggerTest() {
    [CmdletBinding(SupportsShouldProcess=$true)]
    Param (
        [Parameter(Mandatory=$true,HelpMessage="Provide the name of the logger.")]
        [string]$loggerName
    )

    [Reflection.Assembly]::LoadFile("C:\Program Files\WindowsPowerShell\Modules\ToolsTest\nlog.dll")

    # Creater logger object
    $logger = [NLog.LogManager]::GetLogger($loggerName)

    return $logger
}

Export-ModuleMember -Function Get-NewLoggerTest
```

Now I create a new logger by issuing:

```
Import-Module ToolsTest -Force
# Create a new logger
$logNew = Get-NewLoggerTest -loggerName "TEST Logger"
```

The problem i now have is that i have to reference the logging object by using

```
$logNew[1].Debug("Debug Message")
```

`$logNew.Debug` returns an error because somehow multiple objects are returned.

If I do a

```
$newLog | gm
```

it returns multiple type names:

```
TypeName: System.Reflection.RuntimeAssembly
TypeName: NLog.Logger
```

I only care for the NLog one, any ideas how i can get rid of the other one?

Of course I can reassign it like

```
$logNew = $logNew[1]
```

but that's an extra step I want to avoid.

Comment: I'm not sure if this is a PS or NLog issue. Anyway as work around you could do `return @($logger)[1]` in `Get-NewLoggerTest`.

Comment: Others playing with NLog and PowerShell: https://github.com/NLog/NLog/issues/233

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think i found the solution.

Moving

```
[Reflection.Assembly]::LoadFile("C:\Program Files\WindowsPowerShell\Modules\ToolsTest\nlog.dll")
```

outside the function, solved the problem. I am not sure why, but it works now.